# Read multiple tables from csv with fread and deal with blank files

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I was given a `.csv` file that roughly looks like this
[image: csv file]

except that it contains some 120 tables to the right, most of them of differing lengths. For a reproducible example purpose, find the file of the image [here](https://filedn.com/luXIBL3XBsNkg3N0pkfH8lf/foros/testFread.csv).

I'm reading the tables with `data.table::fread` like this:

```
t1 <- fread("testFread.csv", skip = 1, select = 1:2)
t2 <- fread("testFread.csv", skip = 1, select = 4:5)
```

but the `t2` table, being shorter, has a lot of empty rows. Please notice that they aren't `NA` rows. They are `""` rows. The reason for this is pretty clear if I open the `.csv` file in a text editor: row 6 is

> abr,4,,,

That's why `blank.lines.skip` and `fill` arguments to `fread` don't work (there are some questions in SO about those subjects, but all of those I checked deal with only one table in the csv).

So if I want to drop all the blank lines, I have to do

```
t2 <- t2[animal != "", ]
```

The problem is I have about 120 tables and, if I decide to follow this path, will have to hard code the names of the first columns of each table.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to load those multiple tables from a csv?
2. How could I, programatically, drop those blank lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the entire csv and use a function to get the subsets out of it. A sample done in base R is below,

```
full_csv <- read.csv("test.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

get_subset <- function(data, start, end) {
    data <- data[ 2:nrow(data), start:end ]
    full_row_data <- apply( data[ , names(data)], 1, paste, collapse = "" )
    data[ full_row_data != "", ]
}

get_subset(full_csv, 1, 2)
```